# Problem with adding options dynamically to multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, multi-select

I am trying to add options to multiselect dynamically through AJAX:

```html
<select size='2' name="CraftCode" id=@ccrf class="form-control js-select manualentrydd" ></select>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "GetCraftCodes",
  data: {
    JobNum: jobnum.toString()
  },
  async: false,
  content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(d) {
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      $('.manualentrydd').append("<option value=\"" + d[i].craftCodeId + "\">" + d[i].craftCode + "</option>");
    }
  }
  $(".manualentrydd").multiselect("refresh");,
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return false;
    // TODO: Show error
  }
});
```

this code successfully able to add options to my select , i can see that on inspect element but the required li is not showing and hence my multiselect not showing any options..
im attaching the screenshot of inspect element[image]

Comment: You probably need to re-initialize whatever it was that _turned_ your `select` element into such a custom HTML structure to begin with.

Comment: added  `$(".manualentrydd").multiselect("refresh");` but still not getting it

Comment: You can not add it _there_, that would just be a syntax error to begin with. This belongs _into_ the success callback.

Comment: I formatted your code for you. The error in the syntax should now be much more obvious. I'd suggest you use an IDE which formats the code properly for you to avoid mistakes like this. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. i am already using IDE but this mistake was made when i posted a question @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: But even without this mistake my problem is not solved @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "addOption" function of multiselect to add your new options like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "GetCraftCodes",
  data: {
    JobNum: jobnum.toString()
  },
  async: false,
  content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(d) {
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {      
        $('.manualentrydd').multiSelect('addOption', { value: d[i].craftCodeId, text:  d[i].craftCode });
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return false;
    // TODO: Show error
  }
});
```

Comment: Just for reference, see [multiselect.js usage](http://loudev.com/#usage). (Assuming that's the correct plugin.)

Comment: What version of multiselect.js are you using? Doesn't seem like the most recent one.